# Batched Cosine Similarity in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, vectorization, cosine-similarity

Inputs:

- Tensor `a` of shape `[batch_size, n, d]`
- Tensor `b` of shape `[batch_size, m, d]`

Output:

- Tensor `c` of shape `[batch_size, n, m]` where `c[i, j, k]` is the cosine similarity between `a[i, j]` and `b[i, k]`

How to implement this efficiently in PyTorch (preferably without `for` loops)?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```py
c = torch.cosine_similarity(a.unsqueeze(2), b.unsqueeze(1), dim=-1)
```